# UITapGestureRecognizer in Subview of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have two subclassed `UITableViewCell`s. The first (NormalCell) is used as the default reusable cell and the second (DetailCell) is inserted only when a user taps on an existing cell. The DetailCell has many subviews in its `contentView`, to some of which I have programmatically added `UITapGestureRecognizer`s. This all works fine but I have a problem.

If while the detail cell was open and one of the gesture recognizers was called upon, then, after I remove the detail cell, if I tap on another cell, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not called. If I tap a second time it is called. Is this possibly caused by the added gesture recognizers? I have seen people here on SO that say it is not a problem to add gesture recognizers to subviews of `UITableViewCell`s so I am curious about that.

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I have tried removing the gesture recognizers from the subviews when I am removing the cell from the table, but it didn't change anything. My suspicion is that the problem is created when the gesture recognizer is used.

Also, I tried changing the target of the gesture recognizers to the another view controller to see if that was the problem, but that didn't work either. Is it a problem that the type of gesture recognizer I am using is a tap recognizer? Does that conflict with the default recognizers of the cells?